# Lua state lifetime

Tags: c, lua

I am using Lua in a microcontroller environment, and recently I had some crashes related to corruption of the heap data.

The issue was tracked down to be the following sequence:

1. Call to `lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)` without checking the return value.
2. Call to another function, again with `lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)`, this time checking the return value.
3. Step 2 fails (as in fact step 1 had failed, but I didn't catch it), and calls `lua_close(L)`;
4. During `lua_close(L)` memory is deallocated. At this stage the memory manager detects a corruption to the heap, and the firmware crashes.

I would like to ask, at which cases can a Lua state be invalid? (And thus no other operations are allowed).

- Is it always safe to call `lua_close()`?
- If a `lua_pcall()` fails, is it allowed to use again `lua_pcall()` calling another function?
- In case `lua_pcall()` fails with "not enough memory", can any assumptions be made about the memory state? Can `lua_close()` be called then, or generally any other Lua API function?

Comment: Try to ask on Lua mailing list.